# If I don't think that someone would leave Christianity, is it recommended to guide them to more monotheistic/non-Trinitarian Christianity?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, avodah-zarah, christianity, noahidism

Let's say as a hypothetical: I'm in an argument with a typical trinitarian Christian and they are absolutely stubborn. I can show them all the proofs of the incoherence of the topic of trinity and everything, but they absolutely refuse to abandon Christianity due to cultural reasons, personal reasons or whatever else and don't want to become a B'nei Noach fully (in the sense of recognizing the Talmud, etc.) or become a Jew. However, there are people like [Yahya ibn Adi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahya_ibn_Adi) (893 - 974 CE) historically, or contemporary sects like [Biblical Unitarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_unitarianism) and the like, who embrace absolute monotheism, question the notion of bodily incarnation, etc. Now, in this scenario, would it be advisable to push them more towards the non-Trinitarian models which would get them closer to our position or just stop engaging?

The reason why I'm asking this is because I know that leading others to other religions is considered sinful. However, leading someone towards a sect of the same religion which they're already practicing which is closer to the Noahide code might be permissible/advisable if not recommended, but I'm not sure so I wanted to get input here.

So is this halachically allowed, and according to Jewish sources, is this a recommended course of action to reaching out to someone?

**EDIT:** I'm not sure as to why this question was closed, but I'm adding this just to clarify: I am using the example of Christianity just for the hypothetical's sake because there would likely be more information about this case in the Jewish texts (but in theory, any other similar religion can be substituted), and I'm simply asking whether pushing someone from a less monotheistic sect within the same religion to a more monotheistic sect would be permitted and whether such a course of action is recommended according to different Rabbinical rulings or views.

So I'm not sure how this is off-topic because the question is about halacha and Rabbinical views of the action and not about anything outside of Judaism.

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/136539/31534

Comment: @RabbiKaii Yes I know about that question because I was literally the one who answered it. This is not a similar question however, because it's not about encouraging them to adopt a different religion, but a different sect or simply a different interpretation/view within the same religion (or even the same sect/denomination in some cases).

Comment: As a former Christian in my opinion, it’s not even worth arguing with them.  We grew up being taught not to question our leaders and we were not taught to look into church history etc.  Worse if we did bring anything up that contradicted the so called gospel we’d be told were wrong, or the Spirit of the Lotd hasn’t revealed this or that to us.  I was shocked and confronted with the truth, then began to listen to rabbis.

Comment: As my father likes to say: never wrestle with a pig. You'll both wind up in the mud, but what's worse, the pig enjoys it.

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: I really don't see why this question is completely different from the one @RabbiKaii [linked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136539/is-encouraging-islam-amongst-the-gentiles-considered-a-positive-act-or-a-negativ?noredirect=1&lq=1). The context might be different, but the approach would be the same.

Comment: @Shmuel How about you read it again then because the context is completely different?